# Need help understanding TCP sequence number and ACK number

Tags: tcp

How is the sequence number generated? Let's say the sender sends 2 packets:

seq number: 68   ACK number: 69   Length: 62 bytes
seq number: 130  ACK number: 131   Length: 62 bytes

And then recieves a packet from the reciever with sequence number 131 og ACK number 130, what will the sequence number be the next time the sender sends a packet? Is it 131+62=193?

Answer (score 1):

"When a host initiates a TCP session, its initial sequence number is effectively random; it may be any value between 0 and 4,294,967,295, inclusive. "

```
At the sender:
- Send one packet, and keep track of its sequence number and
  transmission time
- Once an ACK is received for that packet, delete the stored
  sequence number, and send a new packet (using the same strategy
  of saving its sequence number and waiting for an ACK)
- If an ACK hasn't been received after timeout seconds since the
  packet's transmission time, retransmit it to the receiver.

 At the receiver:
- Upon receipt of packet k, send an ACK for packet k
- If k is greater than the last sequence number we received (or if
  we haven't received any packets yet), then deliver the packet to
  the application and keep track of k

Example :
Host A: Seq#: 111 Ack #: 0
Host B: Seq#: 222 Ack #: 112
Host A: Seq : 112 Ack#: 223
```

Comment: So one can't calculate it?

Comment: The initial Sequence is generated by Host A's OS at random. The initial Ack number is set to zero since host B hasn't responded yet. When Host B responds its OS will generate a Seq # and The Ack number becomes Host As Seq #. Each Interaction will just Iterate these initial numbers by 1.

Comment: so in my example; the next time the sender sends a packet the sequence number will be 131?

Comment: I edited my answer to try and include an example. If the initial sequence # is 131 of Host A. Then after The Host B responds . The second time Host A sends data the Sequence # will be 132 and Ack # will be Host B's seq #

Comment: What if the host sends 2 packet at once with sequence numbers 68 and 130. The next time host A sends is the sequence number 131 or 130+68+1? I will select it as correct as soon as I get the answer for my question :)

Comment: So when Host A sends it's packet. 130 or 68. It's now in a wait State. Host B will acknowledge (or respond) to the packet. So if it sends a response to 130, the next time Host A sends data its sequence number will be 131.

Comment: I'll edit my answer again with an example. Hopefully it'll answer your question

Comment: Host B's sequence number is 131. So the next time host A sends data its sequence number will be 131?

Comment: As simple as I can put it. Once a Packet from Host A is Acknowledged by Host B. The next time Host A sends data it will be Sequence# +1 of the Ack packet. Not the sum of the 2 packets.

Comment: so the sequence number will be 131

Comment: but in this video he doesn't do it why? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2aEoGV5MBE